# Hover text for Marker in Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have a custom editor with problem markers.
The markers display correctly in the "problems" view with icon, location and text, and the problem icons display correctly in the left margin of the editor.

I would like to display the same error message text in a popup when hovering over the problem marker icon in the margin, just as it happens in the Java editor. Right now there in no popup.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

---

**Answer :**

OK, it doesn't look like the functionality is built-in in the marker-system. It seems a patch have been submitted, so it will probably be added in a later version, but until then it is also pretty easy create by hand.

1. Create an class that implements `IAnnotationHover` and implement `getHoverInfo()`.
2. Return the class in `getAnnotationHover()` method in the `SourceViewerConfiguration`.
3. In `getHoverInfo()` method, call `ISourceViewer.getAnnotationModel().getAnnotationIterator()` to get all markers.
4. Select the marker(s) that correspond to the line number, and return the marker text.

Comment: The answer should be posted as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=282033) bug in eclipse plug-in xtext proposes a patch to show a marker tooltip on hover and status line. If you look at the attached patches you could find the answers you need.

Answer (score 11):

In your class that extends org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewerConfiguration, just include the following:

```
@Override
public IAnnotationHover getAnnotationHover(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
    return new DefaultAnnotationHover();
}
```

this includes the text of all markers of a line in the hover text of the problem marker in the margins of the text editor.

Comment: Thanks for the tip !