# How to update eclipse marker tooltip text?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm developing an Eclipse plug-in using CDT.
In this plug-in I extended *org.eclispe.core.resources.markers* with super type *org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker*. The behavior of the marker is correct except that the text of the marker in the ruler and the one of the tooltip when hovering over the marked code is the same.

For example, here is the text of the marker in the ruler:

[image: text of the marker in the ruler]

and here is the text of of the tooltip when hovering over the code:

[image: text of of the tooltip when hovering over the code].

What i would like to do in the above example is when hovering over the tooltip is to have different text "BBB".

How can I customize the text of the marker tooltip?

I could not adapt the solution in [Hover text for Marker in Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166126/hover-text-for-marker-in-eclipse-plugin/4176893#4176893) to my need.
It will be great to have more information regarding this.

Comment: Can you find in the existing case in CDT that has the behaviour and copy it? As you have asked your question I don't quite understand what your desired outcome is. Perhaps a screenshot of what you have now and an example of what you are trying to achieve would help me understand.

Comment: Thanks - i have added example and description of the desired outcome. Hoping now it is understandable.

Comment: If this is for an existing editor that you can't change I don't think you can do this.

Comment: This is for CDT C/C++ editor. Is there a way for extending this editor? how? Thanks.

Comment: Um, why? This would behave differently than how every other marker in every other editor does.

Comment: I have provided an answer based on my understanding of the problem. If you have an example of someone else doing something similar that may also be useful to understand your problem. That said, pay close attention to what @nitind says!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background

In the first case, the tooltip is provided by the marker hovering over the ruler. In the second case the tooltip is provided as a hover.

You can turn on/off various hovers with the *Window* -> *Preferences* -> *C/C++* -> *Editor* -> *Hovers*. The hover you are seeing is provided by either *Problem Description* or *Annotation Description* (experiment by turning them on and off). The *Combined Hover* is a special one that combines all the other hovers together and tries to show you the most relevant one.

Therefore, based on what I believe you are effectively requesting here is the answer on writing a new hover.

### Answer

To create a custom hover that can interpret and present the hovered over data in a new and wonderful way, implement the [`org.eclipse.cdt.ui.textHovers`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_cdt_ui_textHovers.html?cp=11_1_1_39) extension point. In the CDT code base there are already a [few uses](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/plugin.xml#n217) that can be used as examples.

You may want to extend [`AbstractAnnotationHover`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/ui/text/c/hover/AbstractAnnotationHover.java) as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks - exactly what i wanted.